# Difference between usage of ように and ようにして

Tags: grammar, nuances

> 包み込む**ようにして**、彼を抱きしめる
>   包み込む**ように**　　　彼を抱きしめる

The example could either use ようにして or 包み込むように抱きしめる（albeit written 
differently). What is the difference between these two usages? Can anyone explain the usage of ようにする as I can't seem to find it in any Japanese dictionary. (I've seen some explanations for this in English but I generally try to avoid random explanations about Japanese grammar on the internet because they normally don't go into enough detail and only explain one usage.)

Comment: You realize that by posting here you might very well get (1) "explanations for this in English" and (2) "random explanations about Japanese grammar on the internet", right?

Comment: This ように can be found under ようだ (for example [大辞泉](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%A7%98%E3%81%A0?dic=daijisen) and [大辞林](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0?dic=daijirin)) since it is the 連用形 of ようだ. I can't really help with the difference between the two sentences though.

Comment: I may get explanations like that, but someone may also notice my comment and link me to a Japanese source or explain it in enough detail so that I'm satisfied. I Have looked under ようだ and　する on many Japanese dictionaries but they never mentioned this form nor had it in any examples.

Answer (score 2):

"包み込むようにして彼を抱きしめる" means the same thing as "包み込むように彼を抱きしめる" or that you set something so that it wraps him and then hold him.

Answer (score 1):

If there are several uses for the 〜ようにする construct, then I could be way off... but here is one explanation from an N3 grammar study book* that I have been using:

> **〜ようにする**
>   Expresses the act of making an effort to do something habitually.
>   
>   **Example**
>   健康のために、野菜を食べるようにしています。
>   I try to eat more vegetables for the sake of my health.

*Edit*: On the same page, it describes 〜ように

> **〜ように**
>   To aim for a certain situation or result.
>   **Example**
>   早く起きられるように、今晩なるベく早く寝ます。
>   I'm going to bed as early as possible tonight so I can wake up early tomorrow.

Since I am not super well-versed in using these myself, I can't really elaborate further. But, hopefully this will help you enough.

*<sub>ISBN: 978-4-86392-036-1</sub>